# Algorithms on trees. Are there hints that help point the way to solve efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, binary-tree

I am doing a re-cap on CS fundamentals and algos.

I want to make sure I got something correctly.

When I read hints like `bottom-up` and `top-down` etc am I correct that they **always** should be taken as follows?
`bottom-up` --> `post-order traversal`
`top-down` --> `pre-order traversal`
`???` --> `in-order traversal`

I am not clear on what kind of hint would imply to an in-order traversal;
Also is there is a *more complete list of hints* on various approaches than this?
I mean perhaps there are other hints that point to iteration instead of recursion for example?

I am thinking that if I can somehow categorize like this it will help me solve algorithmic problems much easier

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, left-to-right traversal?

Comment: Which in case of search trees is in (sorting) order, hence the name.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom-up and top-down are terms not directly related to tree traversal but with information processing.

A bottom-up strategy is a synthesis: you gain information from understanding observations. For example you try to understand a computer program by first understanding statements near to each other and synthesize the meaning of a sub-program or procedure. The you go further and synthesize the meaning of the procedure to larger parts and eventually you understand the program. Another example is speech recognition where the sensor information is first synthesized into syllables, ... words and meanings, ... sentences and statements.

Top down is the analytical strategy of decomposition. For example, you decompose a problem in smaller parts, which are easier to process.

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same thing. Imagine you have a parenthesized expression, already parsed into a tree, that you need to print out. If you want to display it in postfix notation (2 2 +), you'd do post-order traversal. To display it in infix notation (2 + 2), you do in-order traversal. But if you want to calculate the value of the expression, it's simplest to do it depth-first and bottom up, regardless of how you display it.

Since you're asking for more sources of guidance, I would suggest looking for a textbook or online resource that explains the principles. Working through problems is good, but sometimes it's good to be given the big picture. I don't know of a good one to suggest, I'm afraid.

Comment: May be I am misreading your answer but in your example the `post` and `in` are the hints and you follow the corresponding approach?

Comment: I'm sure they are hints, but the "corresponding approach" is not bottom-up or top-down. It's post-order or in-order.

Comment: So you are saying that `postfix` --> `postorder` and not `bottom-up` and that there are other hints besides the mentioned one?Do you mean that my OP as written implies that a hint like `postfix` maps to `bottom-up`?

Comment: I've no idea if there are other hints (where? it's your textbook). But yes, postfix is post-order. A hint like postfix does NOT map to bottom-up, that's the point of my example. Any of the three orders might be bottom-up, or top down.

Comment: `where?it's your textbook`.Oh, I see what you mean.No, these kind of hints are not in a specific book I am using.There are also in any site that present algorithmic puzzles/challenges and especialy in those that help one prepare on interviews

Comment: Good luck, if interviews is where you're headed!

Comment: Sorry guy! I'm sincerely wishing you good luck with the job search, you misunderstood me!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for references, you should go to places like [wikipedia](http://wikipedia.com), [geekviewpoint](http://geekviewpoint.com/) and [topcoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index&module=Static).

For wikipedia you can search for "algorithms." For the other links, just follow them.